# Is it principled to tip less if a pricey restaurant doesn't accept Visa or Mastercard?

Tags: canada

Last month, I spent $230 CAD at a restaurant. 
Yesterday I spent $150 CAD at another restaurant. Both high-priced restaurants in Toronto accept just cash or debit, no credit. I'm using final prices, after tax and gratuity. I'm just talking about Visa or Mastercard  – I know many merchants in Canada don't accept AMEX.

I hadn't come across restaurants in Canada that don't accept credit cards before – even fast food in Canada do! Hence it didn't cross my mind to ask up front. Then when the bill arrived, I had to leave the restaurant, hunt for a branch of my credit union, drive there, drive back to restaurant.

Their no credit card policy be-deviled me, and I tipped just 5% in total. The manager in a black suit then riled up, and insisted that I pay at least 10% tip. I stressed that it was nothing personal – their no credit card policy was the pickle. But he blamed me for not asking if they accept CCs before I ordered. Who's right here?

Comment: Aah, yes. When I order at a restaurant, my first inquiry is of course : [if they accept CCs before I order]

Comment: Do you know if tipping conventions are similar in Canada to those in the United States? I'm asking because, in the US, there is a "minimum" tip level, and even if you were unhappy with your service it would be odd to tip much below that level (if below it at all).

Comment: Who provided the waiter service to your table?  Who set the credit card policy at the restaurant?  How would you feel if you were punished for someone else's decision?

Comment: What card was it you used to get the money? In Canada almost all ATM cards are also Interac cards, and you could have paid with that.

Comment: One of the two restaurant visits doesn't seem relevant to this question.

Comment: While a reasonable question in general, I'm baffled that this is not closed as off-topic. The principles of tipping are entirely cultural and have nothing to do with personal finances.

Comment: Just so you know, a fast-food restaurant accepting credit cards is not the same as an expensive restaurant not doing the same. A fast-food restaurant chain has more leverage with credit card companies and so it can negotiate a better rate/better terms with them.

Comment: moderators – i rolled back post because the restaurants' names ARE relevant. i didn't get to read one of the restaurant's menus – https://money.stackexchange.com/a/118001/44213.

Comment: @TamaraMilanovic You can just say that - the business names and ethnicity references make this question unncessarily specific

Comment: Do they accept Visa and MasterCard debit cards?

Comment: I don't know anything about the restaurants in question, but if you're paying hundreds of dollars for a meal and they don't accept credit cards, I'd assume it's a front for money laundering.

Comment: Please remember comments are for clarifying the question, not answering it or discussing random other questions.

Comment: @TamaraMilanovic I could list you a dozen restaurants that do not accept credit cards, and they are not all fraudsters or ethnic. For restaurants with small margins, the credit card fees are actually a significant hurdle.

Comment: The moment he complained about not getting a bigger tip, I'd have canceled the tip completely

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Everyone here is claiming that your actions didn't hurt the manager-- but under Canadian law, [they absolutely can](https://www.ontario.ca/document/your-guide-employment-standards-act-0/tips-and-other-gratuities).

> Managers are allowed to keep the tips and gratuities they receive themselves, and generally may participate in tip pooling arrangements if their employers’ policy permits them to do so.
>
> Employers are allowed to keep the tips and other gratuities that they
> receive themselves.

I'd be willing to bet he was collecting tips and retaining them for himself in some way.

I couldn't find Canadian minimum wage laws in my quick-and-short google search (hopefully they're better than they are here in the States), but in America there is a policy that essentially says, "You can pay tipped employees less than minimum wage. However, if that wage + their tips doesn't total out to be greater than or equal to the minimum wage, the business is responsible for making up the difference." This allows businesses to pay their employees less if you make up the difference for them, so their workers only set them back a $2.50/hour instead of the mandatory minimum (those numbers obviously vary regionally).

EDIT: Per the comments below, Canadian minimum wage tipped services law IS different (and better than) American minimum wage tipped services law. An individual working a tipped position will receive their tips in addition to minimum wage, and it will not be counted as part of the minimum wage payment. Employees in the liquor serving industry (IE bartenders) may apparently earn less than minimum wage due to the tipping, but this appears to be the only exception. (credit to @RossRidge)

I really hate the tipping system and wish there was a decent way to do away with it, but sadly, there isn't. At the end of the day-- as much of a jerk as the manager was, and as likely as the manager was to have taken at least a cut of the tips-- this does still impact the cooks and servers more heavily than it does the manager, and it probably comprises a greater percentage of their supplemental wages. As others have said, it's emotional blackmail. You're damned if you do and damned if you don't.

Comment: Actually there is a really easy way to do away with it - make it law that everyone must be paid minimum wage, and that tips are on top of that. And preferably they go only to the actual wait staff.

Comment: There is no tipping in Japan so how can you say there is no way to do away with the tipping system?

Comment: @Kenshin That's a true observation, especially funny in this situation because most Japanese restaurants don't take credit cards.

Comment: Tipping in most of Europe is extremely discretionary. You add a tip only if you got excellent service. It's only US and Canada that have this antiquated system, left over from the days when the poor could expect to be paid from the spare change of the rich.

Comment: The manager can only take the tips paid to himself directly or paid out through a tip pooling arrangement. If the manager in the question was taking the tip given by the original poster for himself, and not to pool as part of tip sharing arrangement, then he's stealing the tip because no reasonable person would consider the tip as being given to him specifically. Also the page you've quoted was produced by the Ontario government, and so only describes how tips are handled under Ontario law.  Different provinces can have different rules.

Comment: @DJClayworth That's is how the law works in Ontario. From the Ontario government web page on tips that this answer links: "Tips and other gratuities are not considered wages for the purposes of the ESA. They are not included when calculating minimum wage, termination pay, severance pay, vacation pay, public holiday pay or the regular rate used for calculating overtime pay." Note however that "Liquor Severs" in Ontario who regularly receive tips have a lower minimum wage than general employees ($12.40 vs. $14.00), and this includes most wait staff.

Comment: @DJClayworth Why should tips only go to actual wait staff?  Don't (at least) cooks deserve tips for exceptionally good food?

Comment: "The manager can only take the tips paid to himself directly or paid out through a tip pooling arrangement." Managers decide what is the tip pooling arrangement, so guess how often that happens.

Comment: @Kenshin :  Unless Japan once had a tipping system and later got rid of it, it's not a relevant example.

Comment: This (currently highest voted) answer and a number of others miss a significant point, which is, in my opinion, correctly noted in rbrtl's answer: credit cards are ubiquitous and you can generally expect them to be accepted. If the policy of not taking cc was not communicated to the customer before ordering, it is solely the restaurant's fault -- in this case, the waiter's. In such circumstances I wouldn't leave a tip either.

Comment: @gerrit No, they deserve a good salary.

Comment: @jcaron Everybody deserves a good salary, and tipping should be reserved to exceptionally good service.  Cooking is a service, so it would seem that a cook preparing exceptionally good food should be able to get tips on top of their good salary.

Comment: @gerrit i agree with Jcaron. Cooks should make more anyway since its a different skill set to serving. Cooks on higher wage with no tip and servers on lower wage (at least minimum wage) plus tips. Thats how it should work everywhere in my opinion. I dont belive that tip sharing works. If you work your but off to recieve a $20 tip, you should get all of it and not share it with others who dont work as hard potentially.

Comment: @GamerGypps Maybe. I wonder though to what degree people tip for good service and to what degree people discriminate based on age, sex, ethnicity, or physical attractiveness.

Comment: @gerrit There will always be discrimination like that however, even unintentionally. Which is why employers should pay a fair wage to start with so it isnt as much of an issue becuase you can still live on your standard salary.

Comment: @GamerGypps As someone who has worked as a server and shared tips with the cooks, I don't necessarily agree.  The cooks made higher base wages with a smaller share of the tip pool, compared to servers with minimum wage and a greater share of tips.  This made sense to me.  Typically the tips you receive aren't just based on your level of service, but also the quality of the food.  Giving cooks tips adds an incentive for them to prepare better dishes, the same way tips are supposed to be an incentive for service.  I don't know if I agree with tipping in general; but pooling makes sense IMO.

Comment: @DJClayworth You'll find yourself getting tripped up at the "make it a law" stage of this plan.  Most tipping compensation practices are done on a state/territory level, and getting the kind of support needed to make it a federal law runs into the various actors that conspire against minimum wage laws constantly.  I wouldn't say it's impossible, but it's certainly no easy feat, and in the meantime we are stuck with the system that currently exists.

Comment: @Zibbobz Canada is fortunately much better at this than the US.

Comment: @gerrit I think we can generalise your point and say that *any worker* who provides an exceptional service to a customer is worthy of a tip, and that it should be up to the customer to specify whether, how much, and to whom, to tip. That tip should go straight from the pocket of the customer to the pocket of whoever he intends to be the recipient, without a middle man, but also without any obligation to do so.

Comment: @DJClayworth By most estimates, US tipped employees make **significantly** more money than equivalent UK ones. Even stats by the IRS put US bartenders at slightly more paid than UK ones, and we know the IRS stats are extremely low due to untracked taxes in that sector. What are we measuring "better" by? If it's wage suppression, then yes, the UK is much better.

Answer (score 39):

There are a lot of answers here gatekeeping the employers responsibilities to the staff, and passing them on to the customer. It is not a consumers business or responsibility to pay staff wages. It's a pernicious tradition in North America that people who work hospitality jobs are entitled to a pay bump fronted by the customers of whatever entity pays their actual wage.

The proprietor of the establishment has made a business decision not to accept credit cards at their place of business. The staff should clearly communicate that decision, particularly if it is not a well assumed fact, to the customers at the point of order/consumption so that the customer has a chance to make an informed decision about their purchase from the business.

If the customer is unhappy with the service or product they have been provided, which in this instance includes the method of payment causing a disturbance to their evening because they had to source different means to pay. It is always a bad idea to blame a customer for an internal matter because you will almost certainly lose at least one customer.

The blame in this situation lies squarely on the shoulders of the proprietor of the restaurant. It is up to their staff to communicate the effects on the business of management decisions. In the world of public corporations it would be a disciplinary offence to berate a customer for executing a contract as stated because it negatively affected your compensation from your job. It would almost certainly mean jail time if you demanded that they pay over the contract amount to line your pocket.

Answer (score 22):

Disclaimer: I live in Europe where we pay people at least minimum wage regardless of whether they get tipped or not. Tipping is not in our culture and leaving pennies or even nothing on the table as a tip is fine in most circumstances.

Tipping is not mandatory anywhere, it is only customary and I know that in North America that custom feels like an obligation but it still isn't one. If it were, it wouldn't be up to you to set the amount and it would appear directly on the bill.

Going a bit off topic but I would also add that it's a custom that a lot of restaurants use to hide behind the fact that they're paying their staff less than minimum wage which is outrageous to me. Restaurants should pay their employees fairly without relying on a tipping custom that customers may or may not uphold.

The amount you give as a tip is left to your discretion and your discretion alone. You decide what to give based on whatever criteria you may deem worthy. If you want to give 5%, then give that. If someone complains, you could actually take it all back and give nothing instead.

Comment: actually they *ARE* paying at least minimum wage. if the salary + tips combined isn't enough to cover minimum wage, then the employer has to pay the difference.

Comment: @hanshenrik I believe in OP's jurisdiction they need to pay minimum wage regardless, though they can implement tip-pooling.

Comment: @hanshenrik such system invites a lot of abuse. Like in this case, the manager doesn't actually want to pay their employees the minimum wage. So they're fighting in any way they can for the customer to leave a tip.

Answer (score 19):

What you did is perfectly fine. This way the staff, at all levels, will be motivated to raise this issue with their managers, which might lead to a change of this stupid policy.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the other posters that to reduce the tips (supposedly given to servers) because of an incovenient policy is poor judgement. You should not have done that.

Also, if you were able to get cash out of an ATM, you were almost certainly able to use that card to pay the bill, making the level of inconvenience very low. Every credit union cash card I know of is also an Interac debit card.

However tips are always optional, and a reward for service. Being yelled at by a manager is poor service. If he had done that to me I would have reduced the tip to zero.

Note: It is likely that the manager was upset not so much out of concern for his staff, but because he has to make up the wages of his staff to minimum level if they don't get enough tips.

Comment: The manager is not the one providing service - the wait staff and the kitchen are.  Cutting the tip does not impact the manager at all, as other answers have correctly pointed out.

Comment: The manager is part of the service. Chewing out your customers for not doing something that is entirely optional shows a remarkable lack of customer skills.

Comment: P.S. This sort of scenario is just one of the many reasons why the tipping culture in North America should be killed with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Let me clarify - the manager is not (hopefully) *receiving* money from the tip for this service.  Them arriving and berating the customer may be part of the experience of dining out as a whole in this case, but refusing to pay an adequate tip does not inconvenience them at all, and punishes those staff who had no part in the manager's actions.

Comment: It is entirely normal, both in the US and Canada, that tips are "shared" with staff other than the waiter, sometimes including managers, and sometimes including the restaurant. And restaurants are sometimes compelled to make wait staff wages up to minimum wage, which means that low tips costs them money.

Comment: I see - this is a more reasonable stance, though I still disagree with it in general as an ethical reply.  I'll remove my downvote because it is tecnically correct, but in terms of whether or not it's justified I still disagree.  Especially because the choice to tip less was made *before* the manager was yelling at him.

Comment: I do say that if he hadn't been yelled at the normal tip would have been the right thing.

Comment: I have a Visa credit card which I can use for cash at an ATM.  I _cannot_ use it as a debit card.

Comment: "to reduce the tips... because of an incovenient policy is poor judgement" inconvenient policy results in an inconvenient customer experience, i.e., poor service from the company. That is precisely a reason to reduce tip. OP was being overly kind by even giving a 5% tip.

Comment: @WGroleau Did it cost you to withdraw that much cash using your credit card? If so then you would be justified in reducing the amount you paid by what it cost you.

Comment: @DJClayworth, Outside of USA, bank charges me one percent.  Have you ever tried to tell a merchant you will only pay 99%of the bill?  If so, what country and what was the result?

Answer (score 8):

You've attempted to affect change in the wrong part of the process.

You tip based on the service that you received during the meal. If the (related, but tangential) service of paying is not a pleasant experience, insist on seeing a manager and then air your grievances. With enough wit (see [interpersonal.SE](http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)), you may be able to get some of the cost of the bill waived — perhaps the drinks or apps are on the house. But, you'd still tip your server appropriately based on the mealtime service that you received.

It's important to set your sights in the right direction in order to avoid impacting the wrong people.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this manager would be receptive to that. If he complains about the size of the tip I don't see him reducing the bill.

Comment: The tip reflects the customer's whole experience provided by the restaurant. If that experience is negative, the customer is justified in reducing the tip.

Comment: If an idiot manager harms the restaurant and the staff due to being aggressive towards customers (thereby losing customers and customers paying less tips), it's not the customer's responsibility. It's like if a beggar said to you: *"give me money or else I'll beat my children!"* If you don't give him money and he beats his children, who is more responsible for the harm? You or the beggar?

Answer (score 4):

You were understandably frustrated and within your rights to do as you did.  Additionally, it wasn't the manager's role necessarily to demand what tip, if any, you give.  As most are pointing out, though, you've punished the workers who at worst made the mistake of accepting work from this company.

One path you might have chosen was to tip as you would have outside of the payment experience, then discuss with the manager how it impacted you and how it will factor into your future plans to dine at that establishment.

Answer (score 4):

It is written on the menu that Lobster Port No.1 does not accept credit cards. Arguably it is small print at the end of the menu but it is there.

> Form of payment: Debit card and Cash only

https://www.lobsterportone.com/dinner-1

I think this may be a bit of a clash between "regular" Canadian norms and Chinese Canadian 
norms regarding credit cards, particularly as you seem to have happened across it in two different restaurants.

Comment: I wonder how often they have people come in, order a meal expecting to pay for it with a credit card, eat it, and then discover that the restaurant won't take their card and they don't have enough cash.  (I hardly ever have more than $150 in my wallet, and I'm hardly poor.)  Seems like a money-losing policy.

Comment: IMO they should warn patrons verbally before they're seated. If certainly leave a 1-star rating if this happened to me.

Comment: Hence why I suggest it could be a cultural thing. I would not be surprised if a restaurant in China didn't take cards.

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica I do exactly that for every store and restaurant that doesn't accept debit or credit cards. +1

Answer (score 3):

By not accepting credit cards, the restaurant saved about 2-3% of your bill in merchant fees. Most retailers bake that into their prices, so it's not obvious to consumers. In this case, either the restaurant charges lower prices, or increases their profit margin.

Neither of those hurt you directly (you were inconvenienced by not being able to use the card you *want* to use), but reducing your tip does not hurt the owner - it hurts the server (and probably other support staff as GEB points out).

If you have a problem with this policy, leave an *extra* 2-3% tip (the amount you might have saved by the lower prices), and let the management know that you won't be returning.  That's how you influence the owners.

To prevent being inconvenienced in the future, either call ahead to see if they accept credit cards or carry around a debit card or spare cash.

Comment: What is the benefit of leaving an extra 2-3% tip in this reasoning?

Comment: It's like telling a dog "you've been very very naughty" with a smiling face and a happy voice.

Comment: @EricDuminil The server did nothing wrong in this scenario. If the server did a good job, leave them a good tip and complain to the _management_. Stiffing the server is like kicking the cat because the dog messed the floor.

Comment: @DStanley: I'm afraid your point of view is a bit too naive. You can be pretty sure that complaints to management will be forwarded down to the staff. Tips given to management might not trickle down to servers, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil Reading some other comments things work differently in Canada. In the US,  tips are given to the _server_ and possibly shared among other staff. The full meal bill is paid either way. So shorting the tip only hurts the server and possibly other staff. I wasn't suggesting giving the tip to management, but to _voice concern_ to management about the _policy_. I don't see how that would trickle down to the staff. But again things may be different in Canada.

Comment: Giving a company extra money to suggest that you dislike their business practices will not be very effective in terms of having them change their business practices.

Comment: @GreySage Again, things may be different in Canada but in the US tips go directly to the staff.  If tips go to the restaurant and are "disbursed" to the staff then I agree that it would not be as effective.

Comment: Setting the matter of the extra 2-3% tip aside, how do you suggest one go about complaining to "management"? How easy is it to really get in touch with owner(s) of a restaurant? If you somehow manage to find an email contact, you'll probably be given a polite reply, then promptly dismissed. And if you took it to social media (including online review sites), then you have a chance to make some impact, but you'll end up hurting the serving staff by dissuading potential customers of the restaurant. And I don't think that's something someone willing to tip extra really wants, is it?

Comment: @Deepak How about asking the server to speak to their manager (assuring the server that your concern is not about them)? Why does it need to be done passively online?

Comment: @DStanley You're basically asking an employee to bear bad news (or even challenge) their boss (without even being there in person to support them). At best, they will be ignored (and nothing will change). At worst, the boss will "shoot the messenger" and the employee will suffer for it. I may be a little presumptuous here, but an "organisation" that doesn't follow norms with regard to consumers (like adopting the most common payment option) is likely to be regressive in its treatment of staff as well.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry I phrased that poorly. I meant asking the server if _you_ could speak to the manager, not making the server the messenger. As in "Your service was great, but I have a question I'd like to speak to your manager about regarding the payment policies. Would you mind having them come to our table?" In hindsight, it doesn't sound like the manager would have been too receptive in this case, but stiffing the server is certainly not the right solution.

Comment: The OP did end up communicating with the on-site manager. Maybe tensions were already high at that point with the OP being riled up about the bad experience and the manager being riled up about the lousy tip, but the OP did get to give feedback to the manager about the no-CC policy. And his response was simply that OP should've checked first. Nothing about considering a review of the policy. I'm sorry, but your answer and clarifications in the comments don't seem like an effective strategy to me. Playing "Mr Nice Guy" won't work with businesses that don't want to change. (cont'd)...

Comment: ... I stand by my suggestion of giving scathing reviews online to publicly shame the establishment. That's really the only thing that might realistically effect a change for the better - pressure from consumers telling each other about a lousy policy then collectively voting with their wallets. Tip or no tip, restaurant staff *will* be hurt eventually if there's a downturn in business, but that can't be helped.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty simple, but everyone conflates two aspects: 
1) **A company can determine what type of valid payment they accept** (within limits). It is up to you to make sure that you have a matching way to pay. **Being angry for not being able to pay with credit card is totally on you**. Don't be such an angry person, consider to check in advance. There are good reasons to not accept certain card systems, as they often come with additional cost for the business owner.

2) **There is no legal tipping lower limit, so the manager demanding you pay a certain amount of tip is unreasonable on his part and yes, pretty insulting**. That is, unless they clearly state that a 10% tip is to be added to the bill in general, i.e. it's a general service fee rather than a tip (then he should point that out).

So it seems we have two people who just want it their ways locked horns here.

Comment: They whould ensure people know payment methods available, tough. For example in Italy business owners have to accept CCs.

Comment: @beppe9000 Can you back that up? All information I find is just that it is common for some types of businesses to accept some types of credit cards, e.g. "Virtually all midrange and top-end hotels accept credit cards, as do most restaurants and large shops. Some cheaper pensioni (pensions), trattorias and pizzerias only accept cash. Don’t rely on credit cards at smaller museums or galleries", from here https://www.lonelyplanet.com/italy/a/nar-gr/money-and-costs/359845

Comment: @beppe9000 and some other comment pointed actually out the restaurant had it even in fine-print. My main point however, credit cards are not commonly a payment anyone has to accept. They come with additional fees and are a privately organized payment option, so it is on the customer to make sure this way to pay is supported.

Comment: "That is, unless they clearly state that a 10% tip is to be added to the bill in general, i.e. it's a general service fee rather than a tip (then he should point that out)." In these cases, the gratuity is included as a line-item on the bill and cannot be subverted by the customer.

Comment: @FrankHopkins the Monti government introduced that in 2014 with the approval of decree-law n. 179/2012 in order to steer people towards electronic payment, which in turn would result in a reduction of tax evasion. After various modifications (latest: Balance Law in 2016) business owners have to offer the option to use a CC for transactions greater than 5€. The fun thing is that having a penalty for lack of compliance was deemed unconstitutional because of article 23 of the constitution. In practical terms that means that most of shops in cities have a POS but some don't because of commissions.

Comment: @beppe9000 Ah, interesting law, that's a good point for all those "conspiracy theorists" fearing governments want to limit the use of cash as it also limits the amount that is allowed to be paid in cash. So, indeed, in Italy you'd be right to assume you can pay with CC, but the appropriate action then wouldn't be to withhold a tip, but to report that place to the authorities (or threaten). A Source: https://vademecumitalia.com/how-to-pay-in-italy-payment-instruments-limits-to-the-use-of-cash-and-checks-creditdebitrechargeable-cards-and-wire-transfers-extinguishing-a-debt-under-italian-law/

Comment: @FrankHopkins Yes. If the new 2020 balance law passes they will actually be fined (30€ for each refused transaction). Also, you could refuse to pay on the spot and arrange to pay at a later time (wire transfer the next day, for example). BTW prices in italy are set in a way that tipping is entirely optional and never expected.

Answer (score -1):

I used to work at a small but successful deli right off the Main tourist street of a small historic downtown area. The owner did not take credit cards either, but had an ATM about 10 feet from the register. The ATM charged $3 for each transaction. You know damn well everyone knew exactly what he was doing- almost half of the customers would walk up to the register to pay and were then informed of the no credit card policy. Many of them protested, a few got really angry. A few refused to use that ATM and would instead walk 2 blocks down to the BoA to use the free ATM. Now a server *always* prefers cash tips to credit tips, the latter having to be reported as income, but I guarantee this ATM was not put there to encourage additional cash tips. As I had no metric to determine whether or not one would make more tips if we had accepted cards, I really can't say whether the policy helped or hurt the staff. I would only hope that the customers disdain for an obvious ploy to cheat people out of $3 additional dollars, in a time when taking credit cards was pretty much universally accepted, would not cause them to take it out on the person who served them.

(Granted the tips were a lot lower there than at a fine dining restaurant; a $5 tip would be considered good for a 1-top. At a nice place like where OP went, a $5 tip would be an insult- even more so than simply leaving nothing. Remember the redneck in the movie "Waiting"?)

As a former server, I can only say please, never penalize the server for something they cannot control.

Regarding that place, they likely get less charges in merchant fees when they run cards as debit. They might even have the option to take credit cards, but they just tell people that they cant to save money.

So to answer your question- so long as we have determined that is is NOT the server's fault, I would say the market dictates who is right and who is wrong here. If the majority of the restaurants in that area all accept credit, and this place is the one exception, then its their fault. However if there really is no set standard, and half do take credit and half do not, for example, then its your fault.

Comment: Aa a new customer I would expect to  be explicitly warned, unless no shops in area accept cc. Same about cards in general, especially in a first world country.

Comment: @Gnudiff coming from a first world country, I would never expect any shop/restaurant to accept credit cards unless they advertise so (or I clarified). It's not the official currency and costs additional fees, so a service on their end. I would consider it normal in hotels due to their international target audience and the fact that you typically have to use one for reservation anyway, which is a big enough indicator.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Of course it is the official currency, it's almost 2020.

Comment: @towe arguing with  "modern times" would mean we all use bitcoin or the like^^ And credit cards surely are no currency. Same with Paypal etc. They are widely used, that doesn't make them an official payment option anyone has to support.